# "Through" or "throughout"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

In the conclusion of an essay, which fits better?

> **Through** this experience, ...
>
> **Throughout** this experience, ...

It sounds better to me with *throughout*, but I really do not know why. Any explicit example will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because they have different meanings, more context is required to identify the appropriate/correct choice. Since you're writing a conclusion, "through" is probably correct in the context. (Just speculating)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the Oxford English Dictionary’s definitions of *throughout* as a preposition is ‘Through the whole of . . . in or to every part of; everywhere in.’ *Through*, on the other hand, can mean ‘by means of’. Your choice depends on the meaning you want to express.

Comment: Great, I found the definitions. Thanks for the guidance.